# How to Simply Customize \Itemize to Display More Like \Description

Tags: itemize, description

Is there a simple way to customize \itemize so that the output indents beginning with the second line similar to that of \descripton?

Consider

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item  \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}

\begin{description}
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output for \itemize:

[image]

and for \description:

[image]

Is there a way to embed the indententation feature of \descripion into \itemize (i) on an as-desired basis; (ii) at once for the entire document (if so desired)?

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to keep the bullet, but have an additional indent for the remainder of the `\item`?

Comment: Although about `enumerate` instead of `itemize`, the approach described in the following answer should still be applicable to your request: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79939/134144

Comment: @Werner Yes; to have the new indentation begin on the second line of the itemize output.

Comment: @Werner Yes; that sems like it will do what I want. Many thanks.

Comment: @leandris Thank you for this suggestion.